# Cannot retrieve Boolean value from User class in parse server

Tags: android, parse-server

Hi (I'm new so you'll have to forgive me)

I'm trying to retrieve a boolean value from the column "isSignedIn" from the current User in the User class in parse server.

The issue I have is that every time I try to retrieve it, the Boolean value always returns as false even though I have manually set it to true in the parse front end:
[image]

This is the code I am using to retrieve the value:

```
 public boolean isSignedIn(){
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    Boolean signedInStatus = Boolean.valueOf(user.getBoolean("isSignedIn"));
    Log.i("isSignedIn", signedInStatus.toString());

    return signedInStatus;

}
```

I thought that a parse query may work but I'm not sure if it would be as efficient as if I fixed the code above.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you fetch your currentUser before getting the Boolean value?

Comment: I believe so - That's the purpose of the second line of code in the snippet above isn't it?: **ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();**

Comment: It only gets the current user, you should call fetch on it to retrieve the latest value from the database

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't aware the fetch method needed to be called to retrieve the latest value - thank you!

Comment: @flovilmart, you should add that as an answer to the question. It would be easy for someone to miss your solution when viewing the question if it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @shenstone, welcome to stackoverflow! You should accept flovilmart's answer if they provide one so they get credit for the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to call `fetch()`  on your user before getting the value so you have the latest up to date value from the server!